# How long is the string of manufacturer of a USB device?

Tags: string, usb, device, product

Does exist an official documentation detailing the maximum length of the  string descriptor that represents Manufacturer (or Product Name, Model Name, Device Name, Label, or Serial Number) of a USB device?

Comment: Maybe this could help you: http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb5.shtml#DeviceDescriptors

Comment: I know of the USB descriptors, but when i call usb_get_string_simple() by libusb, for example, it get the string (iProduct, iSerialNumber, etc...) and return the read size. But there is not a maximum size that it can read.

Comment: I have not found any documentation about maximum length, but since I use the libmtp-1.1.0 library,  I found PTP_MAXSTRLEN=255.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Any USB descriptor is limited to 255 bytes since the leading bLength field is one byte wide. The second byte is taken by the bDescriptorType. Because everybody* uses UTF-16-LE string encoding, that leaves a maximum of 126 characters.

*) Mandated by the USB 2.0 Unicode ECN in 2005 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB

Comment: Thanks for thinking of the 256-byte limit; you just saved me a lot of work.

Comment: This answer was very helpful